# 4 Key Value HashMap? Array? Best Approach?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I've got loads of the following to implement.

```
validateParameter(field_name, field_type, field_validationMessage, visibleBoolean);
```

Instead of having 50-60 of these in a row, is there some form of nested hashmap/4d array I can  use to build it up and loop through them?

Whats the best approach for doing something like that?

Thanks!

EDIT: Was 4 items.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You need to call the same method with a different combination of variables each time?

Comment: @TimB Yea - Call the ValidateParameter Method about 50 times with 4 different parameters each time.

Comment: It depends on where these all come from. If you have 50-60 of anything it's probably the case they should already be in an array or other data structure.

Comment: @Radiodef They come from a request (HttpServletRequest) - Sadly I am not in the position to refactor how they originally should be structured....

Comment: @Bitzal Check my answer. Maybe it can be of some help to you and get you an idea on how to go about the rest of this.

Comment: Describe in more detail how you obtain these values and which values and combinations actually occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a new `Class` that holds three values. (The type, the `boolean`, and name, or the fourth value (you didn't list it)). Then, when creating the `HashMap`, all you have to do is call the `method` to get your three values.  It may seem like more work, but all you would have to do is create a simple `loop` to go through all of the values you need. Since I don't know exactly what it is that you're trying to do, all I can do is provide an example of what I'm trying to do. Hope it applies to your problem.

Anyways, creating the `Class` to hold the three(or four) values you need.

For example,

```
Class Fields{
     String field_name;
     Integer field_type;
     Boolean validationMessageVisible;

  Fields(String name, Integer type, Boolean mv) {
  //  this.field_name = name;
    this.field_type = type;
    this.validationMessageVisible = mv;
}
```

Then put them in a `HashMap` somewhat like this:

```
     HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Triple>();
     map.put(LOCAL STRING FOR NAME OF FIELD, new Field(new Integer(YOUR INTEGER),new Boolean(YOUR BOOLEAN)));
```

NOTE: This is only going to work as long as these three or four values can all be stored together. For example if you need all of the values to be stored separately for whatever reason it may be, then this won't work. Only if they can be grouped together without it affecting the function of the program, that this will work.

This was a quick brainstorm. Not sure if it will work, but think along these lines and I believe it should work out for you.

You may have to make a few edits, but this should get you in the right direction

P.S. Sorry for it being so wordy, just tried to get as many details out as possible.

Comment: @BheshGurung what do you mean? Check my edit. Should be fixed? Whatever the problem was?

Comment: This is still uncompilable for multiple reasons. It's not clear what your complete suggestion is or how this helps the OP.

Comment: @Radiodef added a bit more detail. Hope it can help anyone in need of it.

Comment: imo `Fields` should be `Field`, `Class` should be `class`, not sure why you have name assignment commented.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is close but you don't need a key in this case.

Just define a class to contain your three fields. Create a List or array of that class. Loop over the list or array calling the method for each combination.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd use is to create a POJO (or some POJOs) to store the values as attributes and validate attribute by attribute.

Since many times you're going to have the same validation per attribute type (e.g. dates and numbers can be validated by range, strings can be validated to ensure they´re not null or empty, etc), you could just iterate on these attributes using reflection (or even better, using annotations).

If you need to validate on the POJO level, you can still reuse these attribute-level validators via composition, while you add more specific validations are you´re going up in the abstraction level (going up means basic attributes -> pojos -> pojos that contain other pojos -> etc).

Passing several basic types as parameters of the same method is  not good because the parameters themselves don't tell much and you can easily exchange two parameters of the same type by accident in the method call.